# Do not allow special characters jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

Have some error in this, can you guys please tell me what i am doing wrong

```
function verifyGroup(groupVal, errorid) {

    groupVal = $.trim(groupVal);

    if (groupVal != '') {

        var splChars = "*|,\":<>[]{}`\';()@&$#%!+-";
        for (var i = 0; i < groupVal.length; i++) {
            console.log(groupVal.charAt(i)+' == '+splChars.indexOf(groupVal.charAt(i)));

            if (splChars.indexOf(groupVal.charAt(i)) != -1) {

                $("#" + errorid).addClass("form-error").html("Illegal characters detected!");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#" + errorid).removeClass("form-error").html("");
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#" + errorid).addClass("form-error").html("Group name should not be empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hgXyq/36/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex

```
function verifyGroup(groupVal, errorid) {

    groupVal = $.trim(groupVal);
    console.log(groupVal);
    console.log(errorid);
    if (groupVal != '') {

        var regex = /[*|,\\":<>\[\]{}`';()@&$#%!+-]/;
        if(regex.test(groupVal)){
            $("#" + errorid).addClass("form-error").html("Illegal characters detected!");
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#" + errorid).removeClass("form-error").html("valid");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        $("#" + errorid).addClass("form-error").html("Group name should not be empty");
        return false;
    }
}
$(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        verifyGroup($('#ipId_create').val(), 'error_id');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAywy/)

Comment: hey dude, thank you very much, it works well, But want to know, 1. what was my mistake, as indexOF should work.
2. IS .test(), will be always good for this kind of validation.

Comment: @SAM it was because of the `return true` in the `else` portion of the `index` condition. see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAywy/3/ the problem is if the first character is not a special character you where not continuing the tests... it was just returning true

Answer (score 0):

The comparison to `-1` should be `==` not `!=`.

Comment: this should be a comment.